# Reading web page with log in (clojure)

Tags: clojure, enlive

I need to download some contents of a web page daily and I plan on using enlive for that. Trouble is, that I need to log in in with a POST first and the authentification of the page that I am interested in is then done with the session's cookies. So I can't just use

```
(html/html-resource (java.net.URL. url))
```

I didn't find a way to do this in clojure. Otherwise doing the reading in Java would be fine as well. In the end it should work as a worker on heroku.

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at `clj-http` or `http-kit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an http-client to create a valid session. You can use clj-http's [Cookie Store](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http#cookie-stores) to simplify maintaining the cookie across requests.